# How can I use the data I get from my database using MySQLi, in Bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery ajax + MySQLi's prepared statements to get data from my database. The problem is that I don't know how to exactly format the data to use in Bootstrap's typeahead plugin.

This is the relevant code:

**PHP:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT GAME_NAME FROM GAMES WHERE GAME_NAME LIKE ?");
        $query = "%".$query."%";
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;

        if($count > 0) {

          $stmt->bind_result($result);
           while($stmt->fetch()) {

            echo json_encode($result);
          }
```

What I get as AJAX response is all the names as a bunch of text:

```
'"game 1""game 2""blaablaa""some other game"....'
```

I think I have to have an array of names and I don't know how to get the `stmt` result as an array. The example I tried and works is (I use the array `allCities` as data-source):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var allCities = ['Baltimore', 'Boston', 'New York', 'Tampa Bay', 'Toronto', 'Chicago', 'Cleveland', 'Detroit', 'Kansas City', 'Minnesota', 'Los Angeles', 'Oakland', 'Seattle', 'Texas'].sort();
            $('#city').typeahead({source: allCities, items:5});
        });
    </script>
```

Now if I only could get result in the same format as in the example, my problem should be solved, I think. Btw, I'm not sure about the `json_encode()` I used in the code. That's just something I gave a try. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

**UPDATE, Ajax:**

```
function handleSearch() {

    var query = $.trim($('#search-field').val());
    var itm = getSearchItem();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "..//functions/handleSearch.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "query="+query+"&itm="+itm,
        success: function(resp) {

            console.log("Server said (response):\n '" + resp + "'");

            $('#search-field').typeahead({source: resp});


        },

        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Server said (error):\n '" + e + "'");
        }
    });
```

**another update:**

In Network tab the response gives the result I want but in this format: `Resistance: Fall of ManResident Evil 4John Woo Presents StrangleholdAge of Empires II: The Age of KingsResident Evil 2`. So without any formatting. `Console.log(resp)` gives me nothing though. Although when I search for "resident evil 6", that means when I type in the EXACT NAME, `console.log` also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should create key=>value store array and then in the end you should output it with json_encode. What you are doing wrong in your code is you are trying to echo and json_encode on every result which should be done just in the end.

Answer (score 0):

post the code that initializes ajax request.

For example this is shorthand for jquery ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: callback
});
```

if data type specified json then callback function will receive an array like allCities in your example then you can pass it to your plugin. For example pseudo code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://blabla',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: dataArray,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#city').typeahead({source: response, items:response.count()});
  }
});
```

Comment: I just modified the code with dataType: 'json' and I'm getting Server said (error):
 '[object Object]'. Of course this message is not very helpful.

Comment: This is error may occur when server response is not in json format. Can you post some info about request? Headers and response in raw format

Comment: John, can you see my latest update to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like server returns not proper json. I guess you can try to debug what server returns. In your case script should return array ONCE.

You need to create array with values of your games. This string should be used ONCE and $result should be result array with needed values.
   echo json_encode($result);
I guess server code is wrong. I dont's see a point in echoing $result because result in while cycle stays the same, without changing. Something is wrong

Comment: May be it should be something like that
  `while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

       $result[] = $row
   }
   echo json_encode($result);`